# TSQL making doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have as following Data

```
Id , TagNo , Revision
100 , 20001 , A
101 , 20001 , B
102 , 20001 , C
103 , 20002 , B
104 , 20002 , A
105 , 20003 , B
```

I want if I pass B for revision i have following Records

```
101 , 20001 , B
103 , 20002 , B
105 , 20003 , B
```

if i pass A for Revision i should have the following records

```
100 , 20001 , A
104 , 20002 , A
```

and if i pass C for revision the following should be my result

```
102 , 20001 , C
103 , 20002 , B
105 , 20003 , B
```

I couldn't make it with TSQl , can any body help me?
Thank you

Comment: Why are A revision records not included when you request B revisions?

Comment: @nnmmss Which database are you using ?

Comment: We really cannot tell what you are asking for here.  If you cannot make this clearer, the question will likely be closed.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I think I've managed to understand OP, check my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with cte as (
    select
        Id, TagNo, Revision,
        row_number() over(partition by TagNo order by Revision desc) as rn
    from Table1
    where Revision <= @Revision
)
select Id, TagNo, Revision
from cte
where rn = 1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0baba)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for

```
select * from mytable where Revision = 'A'
```

or

```
select * from mytable where Revision = 'B'
```

or

```
select * from mytable where Revision = 'C'
```

Comment: thank you for attention, this is not what i am looking for , i want depending on the revision value i get the different, and also i have A-Z revision

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH TagGroups as
(
  SELECT
    [TagNo],
    MAX([Revision]) as [Revision]
  FROM Tags
  WHERE [Revision] <= 'A' -- Revision for pass
  GROUP BY [TagNo]
)
SELECT
  t.[ID],
  t.[TagNo],
  t.[Revision]
FROM TagGroups tg
JOIN Tags t
  ON t.[TagNo] = tg.[TagNo]
  AND t.[Revision] = tg.[Revision]
ORDER BY t.[ID]
```